# Which traffic sources produce the most "product" pageviews per visit?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm aware that in visits and pageviews are of a different scope

However, I've been trying to establish **which campaigns and/or traffic sources produce the most  {{insert page type here}} pageviews per visit**. Not talking about individual pages, but any and all product pages in my case.

So I could report that, for example, "traffic source A produced on average 3.5 product pageviews per visit"

My envisioned report would look like this:

```
+-------------------------+----------+-------------------+
|      SourceMedium       | PageType | PageviewsPerVisit |
+-------------------------+----------+-------------------+
| google / organic        | products | 3.4               |
| google / cpc            | products | 2.8               |
| facebook.com / referral | products | 1.2               |
+-------------------------+----------+-------------------+
```

Is this at all doable using either the GA UI or API?

I do have a Page Type hit level custom dimension set up in GA – beginning to port it into a new Content Group

Comment: I need a clarification: What do you mean by a unique product pageview? Do you have a website that has product pages (pages dedicated to detailing products), and so you want to find out which sources made your users browse more unique product pages on your site?

Comment: Clarified my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drewdavid**,

Creating your report should be easy - you would need to use [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets). In the admin section create a new dimension called PageType, and then with every product pageview set it to *product* (or any other name you decide to choose). If there is a need, send other page types as well (like contact, homepage etc.).

This will allow to filter your basic metrics (see my original answer and [the link to the custom report](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=Sog7FdQ1R6a13vuZg978-w)) -- so you will be able to tell if given source/medium brought more product pageviews. It should be even easier if you use filters -- no need to list the page type in the report table if it has the same value for all the rows... I think :)

Hope this helps!

**ORIGINAL ANSWER TO ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

this shouldn't be much of an issue.

I will start with the easy part -- **the metrics**. Keep in mind that unique pageviews = number of actual visits for given page, as GA help explains:

> Unique Pageviews is the number of visits during which the specified
>   page was viewed at least once. A unique pageview is counted for each
>   page URL + page Title combination.

So I would stick to page-scope metrics, and if you actually list pageviews and unique pageviews, you will be able to see how many times the product page was loaded and in how many visits this occured (=unique pageviews).

Now to pick **the correct dimensions**. The best way for this would be to use custom vars / custom dimensions. If you could set for example product SKU as one of the custom dimensions, it will make this report (and many others) useful and much easier to create -- just pick this dimensions and use it with *pageviews* and *unique pageviews* metrics in **Custom report**.

However, this won't allow you to create a report for historical data. So I suggest to find some pattern that distinguish your products -- one obvious way would be to filter the *page path* dimension. If all the products are listed as "/**product**/ABC/", then filtering the report should be quite easy. Simply select **Page** in *Include filter* and then choose **regex** *product*, which should work just fine.

[image]

Try importing this predefined [custom report](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=Sog7FdQ1R6a13vuZg978-w).

Comment: Drewdavid - what I do personally is to set product SKU as one of the custom dimensions (hit scope) that gets sent when a visitor sees any product on our web. I do this so that I can easily calculate conversion rate per product, but technically this will be the same use-case as yours. If you do this and then build a simple custom report showing pageviews as the main metrics and your SKU custom dimenion as the main dimension, you will get what you need.

Comment: I haven't tried the new content grouping and am not sure how flexible this is for any calculations / aggregations ...

Comment: It looks like the Content Grouping Report still uses the Unique Pageviews metric (i.e. every unique URL and page title combination).

Comment: Drewdavid, then the "trick" with custom dimensions should do the job. It's a bit tricky then to do a aggregations, but if you don't need to go into such a detail, then simply sending the information whether the loaded page is a product page or not should be enough. In your reports you would then use the custom dimensions that would say Product Page and list the regular metrics you would use.

Comment: And referring to my original answer, you would then use filter your newly created custom dimension instead of the 'Page' dimension. Let me know if you want to implement this, I will redo the answer then.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment - I have just edited it so now there should  be everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer, but the number of pageviews alone isn't enough information – I need the context of how many pageviews per visit so I know which traffic source/campaign is most effective at generating product pageviews.

Comment: I see, then you could do a small hack and create a custom metric instead of a custom dimension - and with every product pageview, increment in by 1 (simply sending a value of 1). This will basically count all the product pageviews and you could have them both listed in the report table, with even customized name like Product Pageviews (you can name custom metrics just as you can custom dimensions).

Answer (score 2):

Using the Google Analytics Web Interface helps, but not a lot. You can do what Petr says, and include a Product Pageview Custom Metric (assuming you use Universal Analytics, since you mentioned Custom Dimensions (*and not variables*)). This would mean pushing Product Pageview counts yourself. I do not recommend pushing a metric which is anyway recorded in a different way. Instead, you could even programmatically calculate the Pageview/Visit and update that in a Custom Metric of your own (`Product Pageviews Per Visit`). But this would increase server processing (not by a noticeable amount, but if there are too many concurrent visits, the calculation can take time). If you don't calculate that, with Petr's Custom Report, you will get the Unique (Product) Pageviews and Visits, but not the ratio.

You can instead use the Google Analytics API and do much better, by putting off your calculation until reporting. In my humble opinion, custom reporting can make better use of the API than the Web Interface. For your problem, you can query for the metrics `Unique Pageviews` and `Visits` with the source/medium as a dimension for your API call, and with a filter for your page type (custom dimension). Then you can calculate Unique Product Pageviews per Visit and display in the same report. However, you could also follow Petr's answer, as it makes use of the Web Interface and makes non-Analytics users see the data you want, without need for API usage or programming knowledge.

If you're using GA JS Client Library, then,

```
var myTempObject={};
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    ids: 'ga:xxxxx',
    ...,
    metrics: 'ga:uniquePageviews,ga:visits',
    dimensions: 'ga:sourceMedium',
    filters: 'ga:dimension<indexOfYourPageTypeDimension>'
}).execute(function(results){
    myTempObject = results;
    //if more than one api call is needed (more than 10,000 results),
    //make sure you make all rows appear in a single list.
    for(var i in results.rows)
        myTempObject.rows[i].push(
            results.rows[i][results.rows[i].length-2]
            /results.rows[i][results.rows[i].length-1]);
});
```

Now you can use the `myTempObject.rows` to print the table/report you required! But remember the table headers:

```
myTempObject.columnHeaders.push({
    name: 'Product Pageviews per Visit',
    columnType: 'METRIC',
    dataType: 'FLOAT'
});
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thank You for your answer. :) It seems that the number of visits seems to be too low using your method; I'm guessing that by using a filter I am only seeing visits that **began** with a pageview to that Page Type, since it is a hit-level dimension. I so far seem to be having some success however by combining your two methods – namely by using a custom metric along with an *advanced segment* on the Page Type rather than a filter. At least this is giving me more visits, more in line with what I would expect.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm sorry. I'm glad you at least took the time to (or already) know why the visits were low. You can instead make two separate API calls, one to get visits by source, and one to get filtered unique pageviews by source, and then calculate. Anything you're happy with. Sometimes it's just better to query raw data and do the filtering yourself, seriously. That's why there is GA API. So that you get the data dump to manipulate and report. Also, you can query a maximum of 5 dimensions for a group of metrics, unlike in the Web Interface.
Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Can you please select an answer?